# BlackBerry Enterprise Server Express - Admin Console Page not Found

Tags: exchange, blackberry, bes

I've completed the setup of BES Express on our Windows 2003 SBS Server running Exchange. When Accessing the Web based admin control panel, however, I am getting a 404 error page not found. I've tried it with localhost, the ip, as well as the FQDN but still no joy. Does anyone know what the problem could be?

Comment: Is there anything in the logs when you trying to restart BES services?

Answer (score 1):

If the 404 title (on the browsers top blue (XP) or transparent(Win7) bar) doesn't say

```
JBossWeb/2.0.0.GA_CP - Error reported
```

You have another IIS program running on port 80.  If you have installed IIS on this server, disable it and reboot.  BB v5.x uses TomCat6 as its web engine.

If it isn't this, make a copy of your database file and everything in:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Research In Motion
```

and reinstall install your latest BB service pack.